# Replacing the old index with modified index in the string then pushing it to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, indexing

I have a beginner question. I'm trying to simply replace the modified index back in the original string to create an array of strings. They consecutively uppcase the next index in the following element.
Here's what I have. Can anyone help me see what I'm missing?

```
def wave(str)
  result = []
  index = 0
  while index < str.length
    i = str[index]
    if i == " "
      index =+ 1
    else
      upper = i.upcase
      val = str.rindex(upper) -1
      result.push("#{str[0...val]}#{str[val..-1]}")
      index += 1
    end
  end
  result
end
```

I'm trying to get:
["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
from ---> wave(hello)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` part isn't quite right:

1. you don't need to find the right-most index because you already have `index`
2. `upper` is never used
3. the right range is off by one

Here's a working variant:

```
    # ...
    else
      upper = i.upcase
      result.push("#{str[0...index]}#{upper}#{str[index+1..-1]}")
      index += 1
    end
    # ...
```

You can use [`each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to make your code a little more idiomatic:

```
def wave(str)
  result = []
  str.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    next if char == " "
    result.push("#{str[0...index]}#{char.upcase}#{str[index+1..-1]}")
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring a variable upper but you are not using it.
Try to rewrite your code and this time use it. 
If you are not sure what's happening in each line of code just put **print** in front of it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually I was using upper to simplfy i.upcase. but I get how it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) with [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) in this way:

```
str = 'hello'

str.size.times.map { |n| str.dup.tap { |s_dup| s_dup[n] = str[n].upcase } }

#=> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

Needs to duplicate the original string for avoiding change the original string itself which would return `["HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO"]`

For skipping spaces:

```
str.size.times.flat_map { |n| str.dup.tap { |s_dup| s_dup[n] = str[n].upcase } unless str[n] == ' ' }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't skip spaces.

Comment: @Stefan, missed that part but fixed. Thanks.